# Can not connect to postgres db from datagrid

Tags: database, postgresql, docker, datagrip

I can't connect to postgres from datagrip(jetbrains app). I'm trying to connect, but I get this message

```
    Connection to postgres@172.18.0.3 failed.
[08001] Connection to 172.18.0.3:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
```

All was well yesterday. My db is in docker container, there is yml file:

```
postgres_host:
    image: postgres:10-alpine
    restart: always
    ports: ["5433:5432"]
    volumes:
      - /tmp/lib:/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_data
    environment:
      - PGDATA=/tmp/lib
```

And i can connect to db from terminal, i used select inet_server_addr( ), inet_server_port( ); And know i know host and port

```
 inet_server_addr | inet_server_port 
------------------+------------------
 172.18.0.3       |             5432
```

but this information did not help me, i have same result
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ni8Sd.png)

Answer (score 0):

Port's mapping `ports: ["5433:5432"]` means that `postgres` docker container is available on `localhost:5433` from the host system.

Containers communicate with each other in their network, so you can access your `postgres` container on `postgres_host:5432` from another container, which is created in the same network by `docker-compose`.